# Teradata JDBC double query timeout ErrorCode 1475 in inserting in audit table

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, prepared-statement, teradata

sometimes this prepared statment gives double query timeout

```
    String insertStatement = "INSERT INTO " + Constant.AUDIT_SCHEMA
            + "."+ Constant.AUDIT_TABLE +" VALUES(1,"
                    + ":TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP,"
                    + " :CORRELATION_ID,"
                    + " :ORIGINATING_CHANNEL,"
                    + ":CHANNEL_REQUEST_ID,"
                    + ":ORIGINATING_USER_TYPE,"
                    + ":ORIGINATING_USER_IDENTIFIER,"
                    + ":SERVICE_ID,"
                    + ":CLIENT_ID,"
                    + ":INPUT_PARAMETERS,"
                    + ":RESPONSE_CODE,"
                    + ":TRANSACTION_ID,"
                    + ":REMOTE_IP_ADDRESS,"
                    + ":LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS,"
                    + ":ROWS_COUNT,"
                    + ":RESPONSE_RESULTS,"
                    + ":SERVICE_SLUG,"
                    + ":SERVICE_ENTITY_ID)";

SqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValues(hashMap);
        NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
        namedParameterJdbcTemplate.execute(insertStatement, namedParameters,
                new PreparedStatementCallback<Boolean>() {

                    @Override
                    public Boolean doInPreparedStatement(PreparedStatement ps)
                            throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                        ps.setQueryTimeout(1);
                    
                        return ps.execute();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: what is your question? your question is completely  code.

Comment: I don't know what a "double" timeout is, but do you expect your query to run in less than 1 second?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "double timeout" is?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the error message text for Teradata JDBC Driver error 1475:

"The query timeout expired while the SQL request was being executed, so an Abort Request was sent to the Teradata Database. The query timeout expired a second time while waiting for a response from the Abort Request, so the connection was closed."

You have specified a very small query timeout value of 1 second. If you are getting this error 1475, then you should increase the query timeout value.